# Doesnt select td when using parent() in jquery

Tags: jquery

Check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/ANygj/

When you select a value, it should alert the price. It doesnt, it alerts empty? Like it does not select right.

I tried with parent() and parents(), seem no difference.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Try `closest('tr')` instead.

```
var price = qty.closest('tr').find('td.price').text();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ANygj/1/

Answer (score 1):

The element that you're binding the event to is a `select`. The parent of the `select` is ***not*** the `tr` element. You should use `closest()` to get to the `tr`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.qty').change(function(){
        var qty = $(this);
        var price = $(qty).closest('tr').find('td.price').text();

        alert(price);
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ANygj/4/).

The reason for this is that `parent()`, as is implied by the name of the method, looks to the parent of the current element and continues if the parent element matches the selector passed in the method.

`closest()` looks up through the DOM util it finds the first ancestor element that matches the selector passed to the method.

There's also `parents()`, which looks up through the ancestors of the current element and then returns *all* elements that match the selector passed to the method.

Comment: Also, no need to do `var qty = $(this)` and then `$(qty)`, just wrap it once.

Comment: Indeed; the only thing I altered was the one method, in order to show that it works; the rest I chose to leave alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use "parents", not "parent"

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('.price').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/YhC5C/) should be marginally faster than using `closest` according to http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/8